# forming dictionary with two dictionaries with a specific logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dicts:

```
dict1={"test":345,"testing":123,"reality":2,"factor":5,"user":1}
dict2={"newone":123,"test":4,"reality":"4","edu":2}
```

Now,I want to form a new dictionary as follows:

```
dict3={"test":[345,4],"testing":[123,0],
"reality":[2,4],"factor":[5,0],"user":[1,0],"newone":[0,123],"edu":[0,2]}
```

I want to add 0 if any key is not present in dict1 at the first index and add 0 if any key is not present in dict2.
How can I achieve this?
I have tried the following code:

```
    for keys1,values1,keys2,values2 in zip(dict1.items(),dict2.items()):
        if keys1 not in dict2.keys():
            dict2.keys().append(0)
        elif keys2 not in dict1.keys():
            dict1.keys().append(0)
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dict.keys()` union and `dict.get()`:

```
dict1 = {"test": 345, "testing": 123, "reality": 2, "factor": 5, "user": 1}
dict2 = {"newone": 123, "test": 4, "reality": "4", "edu": 2}

dict3 = {k:[dict1.get(k,0), dict2.get(k,0)] for k in dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()}

print(dict3)
```

Gave me:

```
{'testing': [123, 0], 'edu': [0, 2], 'factor': [5, 0], 'user': [1, 0], 'newone': [0, 123], 'reality': [2, '4'], 'test': [345, 4]}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [dict.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) to return a default value if the key is not in the dictionary:

```
{x:[dict1.get(x,0),dict2.get(x,0)] for x in list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys())}
```

gives

```
{'test': [345, 4],
 'testing': [123, 0],
 'reality': [2, '4'],
 'factor': [5, 0],
 'user': [1, 0],
 'newone': [0, 123],
 'edu': [0, 2]}
```